# Peope API is not shwoing email addresses but all other is working fine in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-people-api

I am new to flutter and I am trying to fetch email addresses from google contacts but it is not showing email addresses. but whenever I put the name and phone number it shows properly. here is my code and output log files

```
import 'google_class_model.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;
  GoogleSignInAccount _currentUser;

  Future getUserContacts() async {
    final host = "https://people.googleapis.com";
    final endPoint = "/v1/people/me/connections?personFields=emailAddresses";
    final header = await _currentUser.authHeaders;

    print("loading contact");
    var request = await http.get("$host$endPoint", headers: header);
    print("Loading completed");
       
    if (request.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Api working perfect");
      setState(() {
               print(request.body);
      });
    } else {
      print("Api got error");
      print(request.body);
    }
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts",
    ]);
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((user) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = user;
      });

      if (user != null) {
        getUserContacts();
        print(_currentUser.displayName);
      }
    });
  }
```

here is my log files.

```
I/flutter ( 9273): Api working perfect
I/flutter ( 9273): {
I/flutter ( 9273):   "connections": [
I/flutter ( 9273):     {
I/flutter ( 9273):       "resourceName": "people/c3630441151529736836",
I/flutter ( 9273):       "etag": "%EgUBCT43LhoEAQIFByIMNjU4OWJSbVNrZG89"
I/flutter ( 9273):     },
I/flutter ( 9273):     {
I/flutter ( 9273):       "resourceName": "people/c6213163730766920067",
I/flutter ( 9273):       "etag": "%EgUBCT43LhoEAQIFByIMMWwyd0ZiZ1pQMU09"
I/flutter ( 9273):     },
```

anyone have solution please let me know

Comment: Have you checked if on the `try this api`section of the [List method](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) happens the same?

Comment: it is returning same. but I have found a solution.  will share soon

Comment: Hi, Have you found a solution on it? Can you update?